# This value on setState callback. A tiny confusion

Tags: reactjs, callback, setstate

**The question**: What is the value of the this in the callback of setState(?)

Consider this:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const {content, errors} = this.state;
    this.setState({
      content: {
        ...content,
        [name]: value
      },
```

A simple update of state ... but after that I call a callback, and try to access to my var **content** or **errors**, what is the value of those?.

```
this.setState({
      content: {
        ...content,
        [name]: value
      },
      errors: {
        ...errors,
        [name]: validations[name] && validations[name](value)
      }
    }, () => {
      // commenting this line, I get the content out of date. 
      // const {content, errors} = this.state; 
      ! this.hasErrors() //if doesn't have errors. 
      ? this.props.fn({...content, students : [content.studentA, content.studentB]})
      : this.props.fn({...content, hasError: true, errors}) //should be emptyField(?) 
    })
```

The content or the error value is a little bit old, so I need to "updated" it getting aging the values from this.state.

```
  const {content, errors} = this.state;
```

Without the previous line, when I try to access to content or errors, I get the values from the previous state. I need to re-declare content and erros, to get the updated state.

Can someone explain me what is going on?

Comment: What do you mean by little bit old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want use the changed state right after setState?
If so, you're doing it partially right, by adding the callback.

But you're using the **content** state from the state before the new state is set. Instead you should be using **this.state.content**

So you need the `const {content, errors} = this.state;`

**Reason:**
setState is asynchronous, so you can't assume the state has changed right after you call setState. And the content and errors before the setState call will only get the new values after the re-render. The only way to access before the re-render is by adding the callback and using this.state.variable to access it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to spread tour errors or content again can you explain more, that what is it actually you want to do?